# How to update SQL Server 2008 table periodically

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a question which I'm sure has been asked before, but I don't know the terminology for this question.  (Hence, I have tried searching for an answer to this question on this, but no luck.)

I am on SQL Server Management Studio 2008.  I have a table that was created by an import of a flat file.  At the beginning of every month, I want to update this table with a new version of the given flat file.  The headers on the flat file / table will always stay the same, and no previous records will be lost.  Data on previous records may change, and new records will be included.

What is the best way for doing this each month?  Right now, my solution is to delete the current table and re-create it with an import of the new flat file.  (Or, I could run a truncate, and then re-import.)

Comment: You want DTS. You'll be able to create a package that runs on a prefined schedule to automating dropping all rows in (or truncating) the table and importing the file from the filesystem. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707786%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the faster methods would be to drop all indexes, truncate, re-import, and re-create all indexes.  Note that with a flat file you could automate using `SSIS`, or you could use a `BULK INSERT` for a job schedule.  For instance, if the file is in the same location every month and all the delimiters and details are the same, a procedure or `TSQL` script that [BULK INSERT](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)s the file would work when called by a job once a month on a schedule.

```
BULK INSERT MonthlyTable
FROM 'C:\MonthlyFileDrop\MonthlyFile.txt'
WITH (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
        ,ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
        ,FIRSTROW=2
)
```

Another approach (one that I'm not partial to) would be to insert the data into a stage table, compare what data are not in the existing table from the staging table, populate those data, then re-index the existing table and drop the staging table.